# Smart location library in android is changing my location even when I am not moving

Tags: android, location

I making an android app that has to get the precise distance between two phone. For this, I am using Smart Location library in android to keep updating my location in firebase. But the location keeps changing in the firebase even if I'm not moving the phone. I know this might be because of the location approximation each time it is getting calculated, but this app needs to perform a function when the phones are within 1 meter of each other. Initially, it was showing the distance right, to 2 metres. Then after some updates, the distance keeps changing to 6,7 sometimes 9 metres.

Here is the code:-

```
private void startLocationListener() {

    long mLocTrackingInterval = 1000 *10;
    float trackingDistance = 0;
    LocationAccuracy trackingAccuracy = LocationAccuracy.HIGH;

    LocationParams.Builder builder = new LocationParams.Builder()
            .setAccuracy(trackingAccuracy)
            .setDistance(trackingDistance)
            .setInterval(mLocTrackingInterval);

    SmartLocation.with(this)
            .location()
            .config(LocationParams.BEST_EFFORT)
            .continuous()
            .config(builder.build())
            .start(new OnLocationUpdatedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLocationUpdated(Location location) {
                    //Onlocation update code
                    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
                    DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("users").child(det1.name);

                    myRef.child("phone").setValue(det1.getPhone());
                    myRef.child("latitude").setValue(location.getLatitude());
                    myRef.child("longitude").setValue(location.getLongitude());
                    myRef.child("pass").setValue(det1.getPass());
                    myRef.child("name").setValue(det1.getName());
                }
            });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Got it, I changed the trackingDistance to 15 from 0.
This only calls the function to update if the difference in the location is found to be greater than 15 metres.

```
//float trackingDistance=0;
float trackingDistance=15;
```